# can't open data.mdb in windows created by objectbox

Tags: android, objectbox

I use objectbox in android project,and it create data.mdb in dir /data/data/com.xxx/objectbox/demo
and then i exe `adb pull /data/data/com.xxx/objectbox/demo/data.mdb`,and I want open it in windows 10 with Access,it shows a dialog
不可识别的数据库格式:.../data.mdb

how to open it in PC in other way?
help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is not an Access file. It is coincidence that it shares the common file ending.

On Android, you can use the [Object Browser](https://docs.objectbox.io/data-browser) to view data.